# How to read real numbers as characters

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I want to do some arithmetic operation to an array of real number and later I have to read it as an input for character variable. I used read statement still I get the error as

> UNIT SPECIFICATION MUST BE AN INTEGER OR CHARACTER VARIABLE.

I also verified the format descriptor. Here is my piece of code

```
 real::la(10), sl
 integer::i
 character(len=5)::lat
 character(len=7)::station

 sl=11.25

 do i=1,10
   la = sl+ (i*0.25)
   read(la(i),'(F5.2)')lat
   station= lat//'xx'
 end do
```

Comment: In your loop you assign to the whole array `la`.  Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

When you have

```
read(la(i),'(F5.2)') lat
```

you are asking to read from the unit `la(i)` (external file) into the character variable `lat`.  This isn't what you want, but is also wrong.  This wrongness results in the error message you see: the unit number must be an integer.

However, correcting `la` to integer is not what you want to do.

Instead, you want to do an internal write to the character variable `lat`:

```
write(lat, '(F5.2)') la(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `F5.2` format specifies that a `real` value is being read.   lat is a a string of characters.   The two are not compatible.

The simplest fix is to read to a variable that is `real`.

Alternative, change the format to `A` (indicating a string), then do an internal read from `lat` using the `F5.2` format.