# Calling Python plotting routine from Fortran?

Tags: python, matplotlib, command-line, fortran, call

Does anyone know how to run a Python matplotlib routine from Fortran? The way I am currently doing it is with:

```
            call system('python plottingV.py')
```

However, I'd like to be able to interact with the script (I want to give the python routine a different input file on each iteration of a do loop. Any ideas?

Comment: You could manipulate the argument to `system` to provide an argument to your script...

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146516/writing-multiple-output-files-in-fortran). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643905/converting-integer-to-character-in-fortran90/30646472) might also be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing would be to give your python script a command line parameter, namely the input file name. Something like:

```
call system ('python plottingV.py myInputFile1.dat')
```

You can then use sys.argv[1] to obtain the input file name in your python script.

Comment: Is there any reason to recommend `system` over Fortran's `execute_command_line`?

Comment: execute_command_line would be better, since it is standard,  but it is not yet supported by all compilers

Comment: Notably Intel Fortran did not recently support `execute_command_line` yet.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://github.com/jacobwilliams/pyplot-fortran) is a basic pyplot-fortran interface that might be useful.